# GLPK for Java lib seems not be found

Tags: java, linear-programming, glpk

I am trying to use GLPK for my java project. I followed the link here https://wiki.nps.edu/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=113606659 to install and config the GLPK for java. And in the java project, I used

> compile 'org.gnu.glpk:glpk-java:1.12.0'

to include the glpk java project. However, when I try to create the test class in my project , then it gives the following error.

```
public class ILPTest {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testGLPK();
    }

    private static void testGLPK() {
        System.out.println(GLPK.glp_version());
    }
}
```

The `GLPK` in the statement `GLPK.glp_version()` can not be resolved.

**UPDATE:** One thing I noticed is in the link I posted above, I have an error when I try the step 11 `sudo make install` as below

```
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
```

So when I try to run `sudo ldconfig` (from another url http://glpk-java.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html), I got a `command not found` error. Can anyone help here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I need to manually add the lib glpk-java-1.12.0.jar into the project.